# "Much much more" in formal language

Tags: formality, australian-english

How would I say, "much much more" in a formal manner?
I need to write a report and cannot come up with a more formal way of saying, much much more. This is to be placed at the end of a list:

> Yearly thousands upon thousands of animals are rescued, £150,000 was raised over 43 “walkies events” in 2016 and much more.

This is a list of successes by the RSPCA

Comment: There's nothing particularly informal about *much, much more*.

Comment: "A lot more" or just "Much more" are both correrct. "Much, much more" is fine though.

Comment: What is there much much more of?

Comment: I was creating a list (yearly thousands upon thousands of animals are rescued, £150,000 was raised over 43 “walkies events” in 2016 and Much much more)

Comment: I am still not sure what there's more of. It seems you want to say that there were beneficial results *in addition to* the money raised in 2016, and in addition to the animals saved annually.  Your switch from yearly to 2016 in the same breath is a little confusing. A full stop is needed  after "are rescued".

Answer (score 3):

> Yearly thousands upon thousands of animals are rescued, £150,000 was raised over 43 “walkies events” in 2016 and much more.

The problem with this sentence is not the use of "much much more", as a phrase, but the fact that you have a list with 2 items and then are trying to add a third item to the list which means "also there are a lot of other things".  No matter what phrasing you use, this will be unclear.

It's not really a list, it's 2 things that you're trying to inflate.  Because of this, it's not really clear it's a list, and the "and much more" looks like it applies to one single item in the "list", not the list as a whole.

Also, mixing a general achievement "per year" followed by a specific number for a specific year in the same list makes it confusing to read, and so this makes the "and much more" even less clear.

For these reasons, I have chosen a different phrasing to imply "also, there are other things".  *Among the ____________*  allows you to specific to what you are referring.

> Among the many achievements of the RSPCA, are the thousands upon thousands of animals rescued each year, and the revenue generated by fundraising events.  For example, £150,000 was raised over 43 “walkies events” in 2016.

Note how I have split the general and the year specific examples apart too.

Comment: "Thousands upon thousands" is unnecessarily redundant hyperbole. "Over 43" doesn't make sense. Were there 44? 45? If you know the number, then use it. If you don't, then generalize. "Walkies" is not in my dictionary (AmerEng), and "events" should not be contained within the quotation marks.

Comment: My reading of the original is that there were exactly 43 events. I take "over to mean during, as in "I went shopping over the weekend."

Comment: @MarkHubbard Hi, to address your points. 1) "Thousands upon thousands": this is an EFL forum not a proofreading service. 2) "Over 43 events" here means "over the duration of" 3) "Walkies" is a common affectionate way to refer to walking a dog in BrE, and the RSPCA is a British Charity.  Thanks for your comment

Answer (score -1):

Would "... so much more" fit your needs?

Comment: Could you please explain why you think that it might?  That would make a much better answer.